# AWS EC2 Private Instance DB Connection

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, subnet

I have a VPC with public & private subnets (Windows 2019). I installed Postgres database (not RDS) manually in the private instance. As recommended by AWS I have created all the security group rules in public & private instance security groups. I wasn't able to connect to the DB from public instance. Please advise. Thanks.

Public instance security group:

- HTTP TCP 80 0.0.0.0/0 -
- PostgreSQL TCP 5432 0.0.0.0/0
- RDP TCP 3389 0.0.0.0/0 -
- HTTPS TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0

Outbound:

- PostgreSQL TCP 5432 sg-0f189eca6a0f783dd (PRIVATE-SG)

Private instance security group:

- PostgreSQL TCP 5432 sg-008ffcfcdec814a91 (PUBLIC-SG)
- RDP TCP 3389 sg-008ffcfcdec814a91 (PUBLIC-SG)

Comment: Can you post SGs' settings. Also have you modified any of the network ACLs?

Comment: I did not touch NACL. I have updated my initial post. Thanks

Comment: Also since its windows, are you sure there is no any default firewall running on private instance which would block outside connections?

Comment: Windows firewall has 100s of rules; how would I trace and correct it? Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: The brute force, would be to fully disable it and check the connection. At least this way you would know that the firewall is the root cause of your issue. Then you can try to pin point specific rules or add new ones to it.

Comment: you know what, I touched the firewall for ping command. your are right. I opened port 5432 explicitly in the private windows instance firewall. All set!!

Comment: Does this mean you have resolved your issue?

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The connection issue was caused by **build-in firewall** on Windows instances.

The **solution** was to add rule to the firewall enabling port 5432.